# Ajax based commenting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Comment model

```
  belongs_to :post
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_presence_of :body
```

Post model

```
  has_many :comments
```

posts_controller

```
def show
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @comments = @post.comments
 @comment = Comment.new
end
```

comments_controler

```
def create
 @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
 if @comment.save
     @comments = @comment.post.comments
     respond_to do |format|
        format.js
     end
 else
     #what to do in here
 end
end
```

create.js

```
$("#comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "comments", :collections => @comments) %>");
```

posts show.html

```
<div id="comments">
 <%= render :partial => "comments", :collection => @comments %>
</div>
<div id="comment-form">
 <%= form_for(@comment, :method => :put, :remote => true) do |f| %>

 <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
 <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
 <%= msg %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <%= f.text_field :username %>
 <%= f.text_area :body %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id  %>
 <%= f.submit %>

 <% end %>
</div>
```

I want to write something in commented are of create action in comments_controller so that i can display validation errors without reloading page. Any help will be appreciated. I can also change all codes if there is another solution to make ajax based commenting.

Comment: A comment out of topic: I would implement http://disqus.com/ for ajax based comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this like this:

```
else 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
      render :text => "oops"
      # or 
      render :partial => "/comments/error_message", :locals => {:comment => @comment} # @comment.errors would contain the validation errors
    }
  end
end
```